# draw 3d objects like cubes and pyramides or cilinders on a aruco marker

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I'm failing miserably trying to draw 3d objects on a aruco marker
as of now I've done camera calibration and I'm capable of placing images on the designated aruco markers but I'm having trouble with 3d objects I think it might come from image points I think I'm missing something there.
Also, I'm doing this in real-time and is there a a way to use already existing 3d objects
bellow is my code

```
import cv2.aruco as aruco
import cv2
import time
import sys
import argparse
import numpy as np
#import imutils

def load_coefficients(path):
    '''Loads camera matrix and distortion coefficients.'''
    # FILE_STORAGE_READ
    cv_file = cv2.FileStorage(path, cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)

    # note we also have to specify the type to retrieve other wise we only get a
    # FileNode object back instead of a matrix
    camera_matrix = cv_file.getNode('K').mat()
    dist_matrix = cv_file.getNode('D').mat()

    cv_file.release()
    return [camera_matrix, dist_matrix]

def drawQ(img, corners, imgpts):
    imgpts = np.int32(imgpts).reshape(-1,2)
    # draw ground floor in green
    img = cv2.drawContours(img, [imgpts[:4]],-1,(0,255,0),-3)
    # draw pillars in blue color
    for i,j in zip(range(4),range(4,8)):
        img = cv2.line(img, tuple(imgpts[i]), tuple(imgpts[j]),(255),3)
    # draw top layer in red color
    img = cv2.drawContours(img, [imgpts[4:]],-1,(0,0,255),3)
    return img




mtx, dist = load_coefficients('camera_parameters.txt')


# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-t", "--type", type=str,
    default="DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL",
    help="type of ArUCo tag to detect")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

source0 = cv2.imread('00000019.jpg')
source1 = cv2.imread('00000042.jpg')
source2 = cv2.imread('00000054.jpg')
source3 = cv2.imread('00000111.png')
source4 = cv2.imread('00000156.jpg')
source5 = cv2.imread('00000000.png')
source6 = cv2.imread('00000041.jpg')
#source = cv2.imread('Kratos_Pose.usdz')
#source = '/toothless/source/toothless.obj'



Aruco_Dict = {
    "DICT_4X4_50": aruco.DICT_4X4_50,
    "DICT_4X4_100": aruco.DICT_4X4_100,
    "DICT_4X4_250": aruco.DICT_4X4_250,
    "DICT_4X4_1000": aruco.DICT_4X4_1000,
    "DICT_5X5_50": aruco.DICT_5X5_50,
    "DICT_5X5_100": aruco.DICT_5X5_100,
    "DICT_5X5_250": aruco.DICT_5X5_250,
    "DICT_5X5_1000": aruco.DICT_5X5_1000,
    "DICT_6X6_50": aruco.DICT_6X6_50,
    "DICT_6X6_100": aruco.DICT_6X6_100,
    "DICT_6X6_250": aruco.DICT_6X6_250,
    "DICT_6X6_1000": aruco.DICT_6X6_1000,
    "DICT_7X7_50": aruco.DICT_7X7_50,
    "DICT_7X7_100": aruco.DICT_7X7_100,
    "DICT_7X7_250": aruco.DICT_7X7_250,
    "DICT_7X7_1000": aruco.DICT_7X7_1000,
    "DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL": aruco.DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL,
    "DICT_APRILTAG_16h5": aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_16h5,
    "DICT_APRILTAG_25h9": aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_25h9,
    "DICT_APRILTAG_36h10": aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_36h10,
    "DICT_APRILTAG_36h11": aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_36h11
}

image_dict = {
    "0": source0,
    "1": source1,
    "2": source2,
    "3": source3,
    "4": source4,
    "5": source5,
    "6": source6
}

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
axis = np.float32([[3,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,-3]]).reshape(-1,3)

# verify that the supplied ArUCo tag exists and is supported by
# OpenCV
if Aruco_Dict.get(args["type"], None) is None:
    print("[INFO] ArUCo tag of '{}' is not supported".format(
        args["type"]))
    sys.exit(0)
# load the ArUCo dictionary and grab the ArUCo parameters
#print("[INFO] detecting '{}' tags...".format(args["type"]))
#arucoDict = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(Aruco_Dict[args["type"]])
arucoDict = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(Aruco_Dict["DICT_4X4_50"])
arucoParams = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()

# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to warm up
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#time.sleep(1.0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    undistorted = cv2.undistort(frame, mtx, dist, None, None)
    undistortedG = cv2.cvtColor(undistorted,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    
    
    (imgH, imgW) = undistorted.shape[:2]
    #cv2.imshow('Input', frame)
    cv2.imshow('undistorted image', undistorted)

    # detect ArUco markers in the input frame
    (corners, ids, rejected) = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(undistorted,
        arucoDict, parameters=arucoParams)

    MarkerLength = 0.04

    


    # verify *at least* one ArUco marker was detected
    if len(corners) > 0:
        print('corners lenght: ', len(corners))
        # flatten the ArUco IDs list
        ids = ids.flatten()
        refpoints = []
        # loop over the detected ArUCo corners
        for (markerCorner, markerID) in zip(corners, ids):
         


            # extract the marker corners (which are always returned
            # in top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
            # order)
            rvec, tvec, markerPoints = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(markerCorner, MarkerLength, mtx, dist)
            (rvec - tvec).any()
            corners = markerCorner.reshape((4, 2))
            (topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft) = corners
            # convert each of the (x, y)-coordinate pairs to integers
            topRight = (int(topRight[0]), int(topRight[1]))
            bottomRight = (int(bottomRight[0]), int(bottomRight[1]))
            bottomLeft = (int(bottomLeft[0]), int(bottomLeft[1]))
            topLeft = (int(topLeft[0]), int(topLeft[1]))

            # upper cordnates
            a = (3,3)
            topRight2 = topRight[0] - 20, topRight[1] - 20
            bottomRight2 = bottomRight[0] -20, bottomRight[1] -20
            bottomLeft2 = bottomLeft[0] -20, bottomLeft[1] -20
            topLeft2 = topLeft[0] -20, topLeft[1] -20


            # testing
            
            #corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(undistortedG,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
            imgpoints, jac = cv2.projectPoints(objp, rvec, tvec, mtx, dist)
            #imgpoints = np.float32(imgpoints)
            srcrvec, srctvec, srcinliners = cv2.solvePnP(markerPoints, corners, mtx, dist)
            undistortedQ = drawC(undistorted, corners, imgpoints)

            
            
            # testing

            # testing
            dstMat = [topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft]
            dstMat = np.array(dstMat)
            #(srcH, srcW) = source.shape[:2]
            source = image_dict[f'{markerID}']
            (srcH, srcW) = source.shape[:2]
            srcMat = np.array([[0, 0], [srcW, 0], [srcW, srcH], [0, srcH]])
            (H, _) = cv2.findHomography(srcMat, dstMat)
            warped = cv2.warpPerspective(source, H, (imgW, imgH))
            cv2.imshow('warped image', warped)
            mask = np.zeros((imgH, imgW), dtype="uint8")
            cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, dstMat.astype("int32"), (255, 255, 255),
                cv2.LINE_AA)
            rect = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
            mask = cv2.dilate(mask, rect, iterations=2)
            maskScaled = mask.copy() / 255.0
            maskScaled = np.dstack([maskScaled] * 3)
            warpedMultiplied = cv2.multiply(warped.astype("float"), maskScaled)
            imageMultiplied = cv2.multiply(undistorted.astype(float), 1.0 - maskScaled)
            undistorted = cv2.add(warpedMultiplied, imageMultiplied)
            undistorted = undistorted.astype("uint8")
            #cv2.imshow("Input", undistorted)
            #cv2.imshow("Source", source)
            #cv2.imshow("OpenCV AR Output", output)
            cv2.imshow('draw 3d cube ', undistortedQ)
            #cv2.waitKey(0)
            # testing




            # draw the bounding box of the ArUCo detection
            cv2.line(undistorted, topLeft, topRight, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(undistorted, topRight, bottomRight, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(undistorted, bottomRight, bottomLeft, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(undistorted, bottomLeft, topLeft, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            # draw rest of cube

            cv2.line(undistorted, topLeft2, topRight2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(undistorted, topRight2, bottomRight2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(undistorted, bottomRight2, bottomLeft2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(undistorted, bottomLeft2, topLeft2, (0, 255, 0), 2)


            # draw the the axis from estimated pose
            aruco.drawAxis(undistorted, mtx, dist, rvec, tvec, 0.01)
            # compute and draw the center (x, y)-coordinates of the
            # ArUco marker
            cX = int((topLeft[0] + bottomRight[0]) / 2.0)
            cY = int((topLeft[1] + bottomRight[1]) / 2.0)
            cv2.circle(undistorted, (cX, cY), 4, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            # draw the ArUco marker ID on the frame
            cv2.putText(undistorted, str(markerID),
                (topLeft[0], topLeft[1] - 15),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # show the output frame
    
    cv2.imshow("ArUco Markers Detector", undistorted)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

here is  an image of what  is happnening

[image: https://i.imgur.com/cooJNxR.png]

Comment: For first tests you can use openCV's projectPoints once you have camera extrinsics. If you want a hood rendering of 3D objects instead, use openGL or Direct3D for that rendering.

Comment: Yes I've done the projectPoints and used them to try create a cube but the object is comming strange

Comment: doube check whether the rvec and tvec are the right ones. In 3D space there exists both, the pose of the camera and the pose of the object (which are inverse of each other with regard to standard object pose or standard camera pose). Afaik, calibrateCamera gives the camera pose, while solvePnp gives the object pose. Not sure what projectPoints expects.

Comment: there's a lot of code. 249 lines. much of it containing seemingly arbitrary stuff like magic constants. please review [mre].